# VPN connection now drops instantly after running route delete. Win10

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, routing

This is on Windows10, my connection goes ISP-Modem-Router-My Win10 PC via ethernet. I have statically assigned an IP to the ethernet internet connection of my Win10 PC, so no DHCP. I disabled IPv6 for the VPN adapter.

I made a batch script that first starts my VPN and then runs "**route delete 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1**". This worked great: if the VPN connection dropped unexpectedly, there was no further traffic and no internet connection until I re-added the route manually.

I recently updated the host name in the VPN adapter properties, ever since then my process did not work anymore.

I can still (without using my script) manually connect to the VPN and then it works fine.

But if I run my old script or do a manual route delete now, my VPN connection instantly drops and I am left with my normal internet connection with its default gateway empty.

Route print while connected to the VPN (before any route delete) shows two entries for network destination 0.0.0.0:

```
Network Destination  Netmask      Gateway       Interface             Metric
0.0.0.0              0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1   192.168.0.xx          4244
0.0.0.0              0.0.0.0      On-link       xx(VPN IP address)    22
```

Did the updating of the hostname in my VPN adapter somehow prompt a new 0.0.0.0 route to be added for the VPN, and that is why my route delete now cuts off the VPN? But shouldn't "route delete 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1" only affect the first line, and leave the second line working?

Any idea how I can stop the VPN from dropping after running route delete?

Thank you.

**Update:** Tried disabling IPv6 for the Ethernet adapter, did not change anything.

Here is the "ipconfig /all" after connecting to VPN, but before running route delete:

[ipconfig screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpSqI.jpg)

After running route delete, the VPN adapter is gone and only the ethernet adapter remains, but with its default gateway now empty. Then I manually re-add the route and ethernet works again.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.